# Double sum optimization

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

Recently I got this question in one of my interviews, which I unfortunately skipped, but I'm very curious to get the answer. Can you help me?

```
int sum = 0;
int num = 100000000;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++ ){
        sum += m_DataX[i] * m_DataX[j];
    }
}
```

EDITED: Also I would like to see if it is possible to optimize if we have the following expression for `sum`:

```
sum += m_DataX[i] * m_DataY[j];
```

Comment: This code is computing the square of the sum of elements in `m_DataX `. Optimization is quite straightforward then ...

Comment: sum the elements and square it.

Comment: Whatever you do with it, it will probably overflow. What's the point of optimizing if you won't get a correct value anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply, square of sum of the numbers.
Why?

Let, an array is, `|1|2|3|`

Then, the code produces

```
1*1 + 1*2 + 1*3
2*1 + 2*2 + 2*3
3*1 + 3*2 + 3*3
```

That is,

`(1*1 + 1*2 + 1*3)` + `(2*1 + 2*2 + 2*3)` + `(3*1 + 3*2 + 3*3)`

=>`1(1+2+3) + 2(1+2+3) + 3(1+2+3)`

=>`(1+2+3)`*`(1+2+3)`

Therefore, the code will be

```
int tempSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num ; i ++){
   tempSum+=m_DataX [i];
}

sum=tempSum*tempSum;
```

**Update:**

What if, `sum += m_DataX[i]*m_DataY[j]`

Let, two arrays are, `|1|2|3|` and `|4|5|6|`

Therefore,

```
1*4 + 1*5 + 1*5
2*4 + 2*5 + 2*6
3*4 + 3*5 + 3*6
```

=> `1*4 + 2*4 + 3*4` + `1*5 + 2*5 + 3*5` + `1*6 + 2*6 + 3*6`
=> `(1+2+3)`*`(4+5+6)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Last thing
what if :
sum += m_DataX [i]*m_DataY [j];

Comment: @user1608933: Simple, you can do it yourself. `sumOfAll(m_DataX) * sumOfAll(m_DataY)`

Comment: @user1608933: if you get your answer, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, instantiate i and j outside the for loop. Then sum of all the elements and compute the square of it that will be your result.

Comment: 1) the cost improvement would be language-dependent and negligible regardless, besides making the code less readable; 2) `j` would not even be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
int tempSumX = 0;
int tempSumY = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    tempSumX += m_deltaX[i];
    tempSumY += m_deltaY[i];
}

sum = tempSumX * tempSumY;
```

For the 2nd case